# Change behavior of TXMLDocument.SaveToFile

Tags: delphi, exception, delphi-xe

In production we sometimes have Exception of type "Access denied".
The call stack is from this line

vXML.SaveToFile(Filename);

where vXML is IXMLDocument.

Problem here is that Filename is not logged. 
I tried this small testprogram.

```
implementation

uses
  xmldoc, Unit12;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm11.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
const
  cnFile = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\test.xml';
var
  vXML: TAttracsXMLDoc;
begin
  vXML := TAttracsXMLDoc.Create(nil);
  try
    vXML.Active := True;
    // Process vXML
    vXML.SaveToFile(cnFile);
  finally
    vXML.Free;
  end;
end;
```

And other unit

```
unit Unit12;

interface

uses
  xmldoc,
  xml.xmldom,
  Xml.XMLIntf;

type
  TAttracsXMLDoc = class(TXMLDocument)
    procedure SaveToFile(const AFileName: DOMString); override;
  end;

implementation

uses
  Sysutils;

procedure TAttracsXMLDoc.SaveToFile(const AFileName: DOMString);
begin
  try
    inherited SaveToFile(AFileName);
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      E.Message := E.Message + ' ' + AFileName + ' cannot be saved';
      raise;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

It works as intended. But problem is that interface IXMLDocument is not used anymore. I want to use code like this:

```
procedure TForm11.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
const
  cnFile = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\test.xml';
var
  vXML: IXMLDocument;
begin
  vXML := NewXMLDocument;
  // Process vXML
  vXML.SaveToFile(cnFile);
end;
```

And with minimum changes on existing code catch exception above with a clear error of reason. What is the best path ?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the XMLDocument has spotty problems if owner is passed as NIL in the constructor.

Comment: @dummzeuch it is not "spotty", the behavior is fully documented. When constructed will a nil owner, it acts as an interfaced object and must be assigned to an interface variable to maintain lifetime. When constructed with a non-nil owner, it acts as a normal owned object where the owner manages the lifetime. Either way, this has no effect on the functionality of the document, only its lifetime

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am aware of the documented behaviour, unfortunately that's not the end of it. I had very odd errors whenever I tried to pass NIL, even though I used the resulting instance only as an interface. If you didn't, be grateful, it was a pain in the lower back to debug.

Comment: @dummzeuch I have never heard of the XMLDocument behaving differently in terms of node/file processing depending on whether it has a nil owner or not.

Comment: Now you have...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply replace `NewXMLDocument()` with `TAttracsXMLDoc`, then you will get the behavior you want:

```
function NewAttracsXMLDocument: IXMLDocument;
begin
  Result := TAttracsXMLDoc.Create(nil);
end;

procedure TForm11.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
const
  cnFile = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\test.xml';
var
  vXML: IXMLDocument;
begin
  vXML := NewAttracsXMLDocument; //NewXMLDocument;
  // Process vXML
  vXML.SaveToFile(cnFile);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that .Create could return an interface

Comment: @RolandBengtsson it doesn't. But the object that it returns does implement an interface, so it can be assigned to an interface variable